# form submit doesn't post text input field

Tags: jquery, simplemodal

I try to submit a form in eric martins simple modal. Everything works ok except that the form doesn't submit the quantity I put in a textfield. Does anyone have a neat solution for this?

My Jquery UPDATED for a better view as asked in the post below

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function image_id_convert(image_id)
 {
image_id = parseInt(image_id, 10).toString(35);
while (image_id.length < 6)
{
  image_id = 'z' + image_id;
}
return image_id;
}

$('.opener').click(function (event) {

  var url = $(this).attr("href")+'/?format=json';

  $('#formVariants').modal({
    onOpen: function (dialog) {
            dialog.overlay.fadeIn('fast', function () {
                dialog.container.slideDown('fast', function () {
                    dialog.data.fadeIn('fast');
                });
            });
        },
    onShow:function(dialog) {      

      $.getJSON(url, function(data) {           

        var contentHtml = '';

        $.each(data.product, function(index, product){

          var image = 'http://cdn.webshopapp.com/i/' + image_id_convert(data.product.image) + '/160x120x2/image.jpg';

          contentHtml =
            '<img src="' + image + '"/>' +
            '<div class="variantsContainer">' +
            '<div class="pop_headerContainer">' +  
            '<div class="pop_title"><h3>' + data.product.fulltitle + '</h3></div>' +
            '<div class="pop_code">Artikelcode:' + data.product.code + '</div>' +
            '<div class="pop_price">€' + data.product.price.price + '</div>' +
            '</div>';
        });

         $.each(data.product.variants, function(index, variant){     

          contentHtml = contentHtml +
            '<form class="formProduct" id="formProduct">' +
            '<div class="variants">' +
            '<div class="pop_variantTitle"><label>' + variant.title + '</label></div>' +
            '<div class="pop_variantQuantity"><label">{{ 'Quantity' | t }}: <input type="text" name="quantity" id="formProductQuantity" value="50" /></label></div>' +
            '<div class="pop_variantAdd"><input type="submit" id="submit" class="button green" value="{{ 'Add to cart' | t }}"/></div>' +
            '</form>';

          contentHtml = contentHtml +
            '</div>';       
           // action="{{ 'cart/add/' | url }}' + variant.id + '" method="post"
           /* quantity = $('#formProductQuantity').val();
           $('#formProductQuantity').val(quantity);*/

         });     

        $('.formProductContent').html(contentHtml);            
      });  
    }

  });
  return false
})

</script>
```

Comment: Which field? Also, `$('#formProduct')` is sufficient.

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to submit quantity in two places - check your URL (form action).
Remove quantity from URL or rename one of them if you need both.

Comment: Ok thx, I have removed the "quantity" from the form action url. Leaves open how to submit the quantity with the form? Can you help me with that?

Comment: So, what happens when you submit the form now? I would expect quantity to be submitted with the form now

Comment: Well actually the form submits but quantity is always 1 whatever I fill in. I want it to submit the form with the filled in quantity. If you can help with that that would be awesome ;) I know my webshop works if the url looks something like this : webshop.com/cart/add/1234/?quantity=10

Comment: 1 is a default value that your form field starts with, I would expect it to submit the value that you/user will enter in quantity field, but it depends on how this part of the script is used.
Is this script used to build a form?
Why do you need this: `contentHtml = contentHtml + '</div>';`

Comment: Sorry for my late reply... The form is build with certain data from a JSON string. [code]contentHtml = contentHtml + '</div>';[code] is used to close every container div the form is in. That part of code isn't visible since it has no use for my question. I tried to change value=1 to value=50 but then still it submits the form with value 1.

Comment: You need another closing `</div>` tag just before the closing `</form>` tag to make at least your form into valid html. Invalid html may be (one of) the reason(s) of form not submitting correctly.
What heppens in `e.preventDefault()`? Does it execute correctly? 
I hope that the code is used once when you are building the form, then there is no point in `var value = $("value:input").val();` because at this point the form does NOT exist yet, the code is incomplete and therefore difficult to validate. The are many reasons why it may fail (html and JavaScript errors are just a few)

Comment: I've updated the code so you'll see my whole script and what it does. I hope you can help me this way...

Answer (score 0):

You can always try

```
var value = $("input[name=quantity]").val();
```

Or try moving the var value into the click function

```
$(".submit").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var value = $("input[name=quantity]").val();
    $('form#formProduct').submit()
});
```

Comment: that doesn't work, perhaps you know a different solution to post the "quantity" with the form?

Comment: Could you perhaps post most of your code? To give a more bigger picture of how you are executing the whole script. Thanks.